# Remove characters from specific locations in strings, inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, variables

Basically, I have two arrayLists. The second arrayList will always have strings that have 12 characters each. I need the first character and the last five removed. Ex: 0ABCD123-0001 need to have the first 0 and the -0001 removed.

The ultimate goal is to compare the two lists...but that is another bridge to cross.

```
public static void getRecap(){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String recapList = reader.next();
    System.out.println("String: " + recapList);

    ArrayList<String> list1 = null;

    list1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(recapList.split(",")));

    System.out.println("ArrayList: " + list1);

    String scansList = reader.next();
    System.out.println("String: " + scansList);

    ArrayList<String> list2 = null;

    list2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(scansList.split(",")));

    System.out.println("ArrayList: " + list2);;

}
```

Comment: ArrayList has a method called remove(int index), where you give it the index of the element you want to remove... you should try it

Comment: *"ArrayList<String> will always have 12 characters"* What does that mean? 12 Strings of 1 character each? One String of 12 characters? 2 of 6? 3 of 4? Two Strings of length 7 and 5? X Strings of 12 characters? Something entirely different?

Comment: Ah, that is confusing. I mean the second list is a list of strings, each string has 12 characters

Basically strings like "0xxxx123-0001" I need the first 0 and the last -0001 removed

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert the array into a string, and get a substring removing the first and last 5 chars?

Comment: I started off with a long comma delimited string, turned that into an arrayList. Would it be easier to remove the characters I need removed BEFORE I put it into the list? Not sure how to go about that.

Comment: I do it quite often, probably not the most efficient way but here is how: removing the first char is easy just set the start of the new substring to 1 and thats skipped. Then get a substring of the last 5 chars. var LastChars = MyListString.SubString(MyListString.Length - 5);   Now just remove it frmo the string with MyListString.Remove(LastChars); then MyListString = MyListString.SubString(1); to skip the first char

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the index of the array to remove the selected indexes. for instance:

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element);
```

array being your array name and the element is the index of the character that you wish to remove. This way you can be specific like the first and last five characters.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the entire string from the list? I may have a misunderstanding of arrayLists. 
I have a comma-seperated string, which I am using arrayLists to seperate it into several different values. I need those values to be subject to the removals mentioned above.

Comment: I would try it and see if it is close to what you want for the correct output. If the commas separate the values into different indexes in the array then yes it should work. Arrays have indexes and each index represents the value. Once you understand what values you are putting into the arrays you can then understand what to do when you want to remove them.